# Does "～の違いだけで" mean "the only difference"?

Tags: grammar, parsing

> 尽きる場所が、家か７階かの違いだけで、確実にどちらかで死ぬ。

First, if there wasn't the の違いだけで I would understand the sentence but there is also this 尽きる場所が which seems to be redundant because of 尽きる場所が. I used the Google Translator and it translated as "*the only difference is whether it ends in my house or on the 7th floor*". So it seems the translator is omitting the possible redundance between 死ぬ and 尽きる場所が and translating の違いだけで as "the only difference". After spending some minutes thinking about it, it makes sense. I wanted to confirm here the meaning of 違いだけで and clarify the relationship between 尽きる場所が and 死ぬ, whether it's a redundance or there is an implicit meaning in it. Also, does the particle で in 違いだけで and どちらかで refers both to the place where the person would die?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first で (after だけ) is the te-form of だ (= is...and...), and the second で (after どちらか) is a location marker (= in/at/on). This 尽きる is one of the indirect ways of saying 死ぬ.

- ～だけだ。
  It's merely a ～.
- ～の違いだけだ。
  It's merely a difference of ～.
- [尽きる場所が、家か７階か]の違いだけだ。
  It's merely a difference of [whether the place where it (=his life) ends is the house or the 7th floor].
  <sup>(`[]` indicates an embedded question (a noun clause).)</sup>
- 尽きる場所が、家か７階かの違いだけで、確実にどちらか**で**死ぬ。
  It's only a matter of whether he dies in his house or on the 7th floor; he will certainly die **in** either of the two places.

Comment: You broke it down so perfectly, specially with the embedded question and saying there are two clauses separated by the first で. You deserve a special Thank You!